# Append Values at Dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following code and want now to add all items of "Produkt-Name" to a Dictionary

```
   for col_number, element in enumerate(headings):
       for row in ws.iter_rows():
           if row[col_number].value is  None:
               continue
           else:
              if element ==  "Produkt-Name":
                  test = {"productname": row[col_number].value}
```

The Problem is, I only get the last item of it at the dictionary. I also tested the build in update function but got the last index too.

Comment: Please provide the input and expected output.

Comment: Please, post [mre]

Comment: Also note that you cannot have duplicate keys in a dict. maybe you want list of dicts or dict of dicts with unique keys?

Answer (score 0):

Every time your conditions are met (the two if statements) you create a new dictionary called "test", the proper syntax to add elements to a dict is :

```
my_dict[new_key] = value
```

if new_key already exists, then you will overwrite the old value with the new one, without creating a new key/value pair.
Hope this helps.

Also, as others already pointed out, please produce a minimal reproducible example, we at least need the structure of "headings" and what you would expect as an output.

Comment: it only stores the last value in the list...

Comment: @markboss As I said, you keep creating a dict called test holding only one value, so at the end of your program you're left with test being the last dictionary you created, which holds the last acceptable value. Please read my comment again and post a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have all items under the key 'productname' you can use:

`test.setdefault("productname", []).append(row[col_number].value)`

but if you want to have your values under different keys you need to set different key names.

Edit: for example: test[key1] = value1, test[key2] = value2, ...

Comment: Is it possible to store it not in a array, so take more objects?